# How do I enable debuggin of Twig when used with Slim?

Tags: php, twig, slim

Per http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#using-extensions:

> When creating a new Twig_Environment instance, you can pass an array
>   of options as the constructor second argument:
>
> ```
> $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
> ```

How would this be implemented when used with Slim?  My attempt is below, however, `{{ dump(foo) }}` results in an `Unknown "dump" function in "forms.html" at line 35.` error.  I have tried adding the script on the Twig website, however, I don't know what to use for `$loader` and where to insert `$twig`.

```
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('../application/templates', [
        //'cache' => 'path/to/cache'    // See auto_reload option
        'debug' => true,
        'strict_variables'=> true
    ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $c['router'],
        $c['request']->getUri()
    ));
    return $view;
};
```

Comment: maybe interesting? http://discourse.slimframework.com/t/twig-debug-mode/535

Comment: @RyanVincent Ha ha!  Just needed to add one line `$view->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());`.  Thanks!